# How to make an element of a dict accumulate other elements in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, accumulator

I have the following structure of python dictionary lists (let's call it `dict1`):

```
dict1 = {"word1": {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
         "word2": {'111.txt': 2, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1},
         "word3": {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1},
         "word4": {'111.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
         "word5": {'111.txt': 5, '113.txt': 1}}
```

and I would like to create a **new dictionary** (`dict2`), where I have the keys of `dict1` and the sum of the elements of that key as its elements. Thus:

```
{'111.txt': 12, '112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7}
```

I tried to do the following code below, however, it is only storing the last element of `dict1` in `dict2`, that is, it is not accumulating the values ​​of `dict1`

```
for i,j in dict1.items():
     for k,w in j.items():
            dict2[k] =+ j[k]
```

The output is as follows, it leaves only the last element of `dict1`, it is not accumulating the sum.

```
{'111.txt': 5, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1}
```

Does anyone know what may be wrong in the code? Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: It's really helpful in questions about a programming language to **use the actual language syntax**. It's unambiguous. This is not python: `word3 -> {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1}` so it's not clear what you mean. Does this mean `word3` is a variable or are these some other structure like a list or dict? Just make the code such that one can paste it into an interpreter and get the structure you are starting with.

Comment: They are dictionaries, where `word3` is a key and `{'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1}` are the elements of that key, that is, these elements are also dictionaries.

Comment: Okay @Mark Meyer, I thank you for your observation. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in the way you initialise `dict2` but can't tell much since you haven't posted that part. This should work though:

```
dict1 = {"word1": {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
         "word2": {'111.txt': 2, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1},
         "word3": {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1},
         "word4": {'111.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
         "word5": {'111.txt': 5, '113.txt': 1}}

dict2 = dict()

for i, j in dict1.items():
    for k, w in j.items():
        dict2[k] = dict2.get(k, 0) + j[k]

print(dict2)
```

output:

```
{'112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7, '111.txt': 12}
```

Comment: To be fair your actual issue was probably the use of `=+` instead of `+=` as @Phillyclause89 noticed.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're encountering here is that you need to use `+=` not `=+`. Step through this [code example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=d1%20%3D%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20word1%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%201,%20'112.txt'%3A%203,%20'113.txt'%3A%202%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word2%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%202,%20'112.txt'%3A%202,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word3%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%201,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word4%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%203,%20'113.txt'%3A%202%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word5%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%205,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%29%0Ad2%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Afor%20i,j%20in%20d1.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20for%20k,w%20in%20j.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d2%5Bk%5D%20%3D%2B%20j%5Bk%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28d2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) and you'll see that `=+` is treated as an assignment not an in-place addition. [Here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=d1%20%3D%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20word1%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%201,%20'112.txt'%3A%203,%20'113.txt'%3A%202%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word2%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%202,%20'112.txt'%3A%202,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word3%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%201,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word4%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%203,%20'113.txt'%3A%202%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20word5%20%3D%20%7B'111.txt'%3A%205,%20'113.txt'%3A%201%7D,%0A%29%0Ad2%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Afor%20i,j%20in%20d1.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20k,w%20in%20j.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20k%20in%20d2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d2%5Bk%5D%20%2B%3D%20j%5Bk%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d2%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20j%5Bk%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28d2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) is that example code with `+=` and a little extra logic you'll see it tally correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are initializing `dict2`, so its difficult to point out the problem in your code. Having said this, below are some ways you can do this problem.

Assuming your data is in the nested dictionary format `{'word1': {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2}, 'word2':..}`, I believe you were aiming for:

```
d = {
    'word1': {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word2': {'111.txt': 2, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1},
    'word3': {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1},
    'word4': {'111.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word5': {'111.txt': 5, '113.txt': 1}
}

counts = {}

# only need to iterate values here. 'word1', 'word2' etc. not needed in output
for v1 in d.values():

    # iterate sub dictionary values and keys. These are needed for output. 
    for k, v2 in v1.items():

        # Use dict.get() to set initial value to 0 if key doesn't exist
        counts[k] = v2 + counts.get(k, 0)

print(counts)
# {'111.txt': 12, '112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7}
```

Or even a simple approach like the below:

```
counts = {}
for v1 in d.values():
    for k, v2 in v1.items():

        # initialize to 0 if key doesn't exist
        if k not in counts:
            counts[k] = 0

        # Continue counting, since above condition will prevent KeyError
        counts[k] += v2

print(counts)
# {'111.txt': 12, '112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7}
```

Additonally, you could also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {
    'word1': {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word2': {'111.txt': 2, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1},
    'word3': {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1},
    'word4': {'111.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word5': {'111.txt': 5, '113.txt': 1}
}

counts = Counter()
for v in d.values():
    counts.update(v)

print(counts)
# Counter({'111.txt': 12, '113.txt': 7, '112.txt': 5})
```

Which uses [`Counter.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) to do add the counts in easily.

You can also use [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here as well:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    'word1': {'111.txt': 1, '112.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word2': {'111.txt': 2, '112.txt': 2, '113.txt': 1},
    'word3': {'111.txt': 1, '113.txt': 1},
    'word4': {'111.txt': 3, '113.txt': 2},
    'word5': {'111.txt': 5, '113.txt': 1}
}

counts = defaultdict(int)
for v1 in d.values():
    for k, v2 in v1.items():
        counts[k] += v2

print(counts)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'111.txt': 12, '112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7})
```

**Note:** `Counter` and `defaultdict` are both subclasses of `dict`, so you can treat them like normal dictionaries. If you really want the output to be `dict` instead, you can cast `dict()`:

```
print(dict(counts))
# {'111.txt': 12, '112.txt': 5, '113.txt': 7}
```

They both also handle initializing for you, so you don't need to initialize new keys with `0`.